# How to use valgrind on QNX platform

Tags: c, valgrind, qnx, blackberry-qnx

According to the [official documents of valgrind](https://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html), QNX is not supported.
Howerver, I saw some questions about using valgrind on QNX. [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453907/how-to-run-valgrind-with-qnx-binaries)
[question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73078569/valgrind-in-qnx-cant-access-shared-library-error).
This confused me. Is it possible to run Valgrind on QNX?
If it is possible, how can this be achieved?
Perhaps compiling an executable file that compatible with the QNX platform? or is there a way to download the correct files?

I found the [Valgrind project](https://community.qnx.com/sf/frs/do/viewRelease/projects.valgrind/frs.valgrind.valgrind_3_10;jsessionid=OEBZSSQUfLf5gV+W-ht7wdVW.tf) on QNX community.
[I downloaded the package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVbju.png)
Howerver, it did not contain files about the arm64/aarch64 architecture which I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to download the source (from here https://community.qnx.com/sf/scm/do/listRepositories/projects.valgrind/scm) and build it.

It doesn't look like it has been maintained for 7 years (Valgrind 3.11) so I think that getting it to build and work will be a substantial effort unless QNX and the toolchain have not changed much in the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot.     I got the source, than tried to build it. Unfortunately, it failed with an error, "m_syswrap/syscall-arm64-nto.S:132: Error: undefined symbol OFFSET_arm64_SC_CLASS used as an immediate value".     Would you have any suggestions to help resolve this error?

Comment: OFFSET_{cpu} stuff should be in VEX/pub/libvex_guest_offsets.h
Thats produced from VEX/auxprogs/genoffsets.c using the compiler to output assembler and then using grep and sed to extract the offsets.  genoffsets.c should contain a line `GENOFFSET(ARM64,arm64,SC_CLASS);` in the arm64 section. Either your build is failing to generate that header or the C file is mssing the GENOFFSET line. That might be the tip of the iceberg though.

Comment: Appreciate your advice very much. After adding the corresponding code, I successfully compiled it. Moreover, it was able to identify memory leak issues correctly in my simple test program. However, when I used valgrind to detect my work program, it exited unexpectedly. The logs showed "valgrind: m_syswrap/syswrap-nto.c:2088 (vgSysWrap_nto_msg_send_common_before): Assertion 'Unimplemented functionality' failed."

Comment: That means that there is a syscall wrapper for `msg_send` in `m_syswrap/syswrap-nto.c` (and you have the line from the assert). That'll be `PRE(msg_send)`. Either it is entirely not supported or it has different modes and the mode your app uses is unsupported.